# How to receive all notifications from an NSMetadataQuery running inside a plug-in (NSBundle)

Tags: cocoa, nsnotificationcenter

I regularly use plug-ins (loaded NSBundles) to encapsulate some functionality. I now want to use NSMetadataQuery in one of my plug-ins, but ran into threading problems I'm unable to solve.

Inside the main class of the plug-in, I set up the query like this:

```
NSMetadataQuery *mdQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    [mdQuery setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(kMDItemFSName LIKE 'Project *')"]];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(processQuery:) 
                                                 name:nil 
                                               object:mdQuery];

    [mdQuery startQuery];
```

And the notifications are caught by:

```
- (void)processQuery:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSMetadataQuery *mdQuery = [notification object];

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:NSMetadataQueryDidStartGatheringNotification]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@ Query started", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));

    } else if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:NSMetadataQueryGatheringProgressNotification]) {

        NSLog(@"%@ %@ %ld", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), (long)[mdQuery resultCount]);

    } else if ([[notification name] isEqualToString: NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification]) {
        NSUInteger theResultCount = [mdQuery resultCount];
        theResultCount = 10; //for now
        for (NSUInteger i; i < theResultCount; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%@ %@ %ld %@", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), (long)i, [mdQuery resultAtIndex:i]);
        }

    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@ NSMetadataQueryDidUpdateNotification: %@", [self class], NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), notification);
    }
}
```

This code works fine running in an app, but when run from with the plug-in, only NSMetadataQueryDidStartGatheringNotification is ever received, nothing else.

I found one or two posts of people wrestling with the same problem, and one of them ([James Bucanek in Oh notification, where are you?](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Sep/msg01695.html)) solved his problem by calling CFRunLoopRun(); right after the startQuery and CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent ()); when the query was done. One problem is that the run loop thus started is synchronous while NSMetadataQuery clearly is asynchronous, the other was that in the plug-in it never got past NSMetadataQueryGatheringProgressNotification. I then tried giving NSMetadataQuery its own thread but again, only NSMetadataQueryDidStartGatheringNotification was ever received. I don't know if the problem can be solved, but I would really like some input.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
NSMetadataQuery *mdQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
// ...
[mdQuery startQuery];
```

with:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSMetadataQuery *mdQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
    // ...
    [mdQuery startQuery];
});
```

(If you need to target Leopard or earlier, use `-performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be anything different occurring if the code is loaded via bundle instead of compiled into the app.

When you load a Cocoa bundle the classes in the bundle are loaded into the app's address space and essentially become part of the app. Bundle code is not run in a separate thread or run loop unless you specifically make it so.

I don't believe this is a run loop or threading issue. What makes you think it is?

Are you sure the object in your bundle that begins the query has not been deallocated by the time the results return? What is holding on to it?

Comment: The search object is not retained by me, because it doesn't need to be. I've run the code with and without the retained search object in both the app and the plug-in and the result is always the same: the search makes it to the finish when run in the app, but not when run in the plug-in. As for the run loop: the problem is not that the plug-in is run in a separate loop, the problem is that the plug-in code doesn't have a run loop at all. Why do I think so? Because James Bucanek (see the link in my question) and others say so and I have no reason to doubt them.

Comment: I'll rephrase the run loop bit: as far as I can make out, the plug-in code is run by the app's run loop but it's not kept around long enough for the plug-in to receive notifications other than the very first one, the start notification, which is posted right away.

Comment: When you say "it's not kept around long enough", what are you referring to? Your plug-in must have a class that you instantiate somewhere. That instance must hang around long enough for it to receive the notification. How are you loading the code in your plug-in? Is the instance of the plug-in's object retained? If not, it's probably just being autoreleased and deallocated, so of course it can't respond to the notification. Plug-ins aren't magic, they just add classes to your app.

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you are taking the trouble to answer my question, but I feel this is degrading into a kind of verbal ping-pong. I use plug-ins extensively, they manage views and persistent stores, react to and send notifications and more. But apparently there is something about an asynchronous process that doesn't jell well with the plug-in architecture and I'm hoping to learn what that is.

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative, all I'm asking is are you **sure** that the problem is due to the fact that the code is loaded from a plugin? Could there not be another reason?

Comment: The code in my question I've written and run first in the app. NSLog messages for every one of the notification, right up to NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification. I cut and pasted the exact same code into the plug-in and the only NSLog I ever received was the one for NSMetadataQueryDidStartGatheringNotification. When I added the runloop I did get messages for NSMetadataQueryGatheringProgressNotification, but never for the did finish notification. I described it all in my question, or thought I did. I was sober and reasonably sane when I did all that.

Comment: The reason I ask is that I have a plug-in that runs a spotlight search and I've never experienced the issue. I will, however go and re-test it!